# deleting a row in a ListView, IndexOutOfBound Exception

Tags: java, android, listview

I have searched a lot through SO, several threads are talking about the issue. But no one actually helped, I have populated the adapter with data and now I'd like to delete a row with a dedicated button in every row, one of the threads had a suggestion: to write an `onClickListener` in the `getView()` method of the adapter. When I tried that, an `IndexOutOfBound` exception emerged. More accurately, when I clicked the the delete button on the first row, nothing happened but in the second and last row clicking the delete button gave the exception

here's what I tried to do, Android studio has suggested that the position variable should be final:

```
public class TimeTrackerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public ArrayList<TimeRecord> times=new ArrayList<TimeRecord>();
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return times.size();
    }

    public TimeTrackerAdapter()
    {
        times.add(new TimeRecord("12:30","this is the best"));
        times.add(new TimeRecord("2:30","I need this"));
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return times.get(position);
    }

    public void addTimeRecord(TimeRecord timeRecord)
    {
        times.add(timeRecord);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(view==null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_layout, parent, false);
        }
        Button button=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.delete_entry);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                times.remove(position);
            }
        });
        TextView timeView=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time_textView);
        TextView noteView=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.note_TextView);
        TimeRecord time=times.get(position);
        timeView.setText(time.getTime());
        noteView.setText(time.getNote());
        return view;
    }
}
```

and here's the error stack:

```
08-21 10:47:20.330  20400-20400/com.example.sam.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.sam.myapplication, PID: 20400
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:403)
        at com.example.sam.myapplication.TimeTrackerAdapter$1.onClick(TimeTrackerAdapter.java:55)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4508)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18675)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: just delete elements from your arraylist and refresh your listview

Comment: @Codebender if I'm not wrong, you the notifyDataSetChange() method, but how can I invoke the method? I can't instantiate another object in the onClick method?

Comment: Try calling `TimeTrackerAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: @Codebender it worked!!! thank you so much!!  I didn't know the "this" technique before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add notifyDataSetChanged() in your button onClick method

```
       Button button=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.delete_entry);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                times.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

you should call notifyDataSetChanged whenever you add/remove item. Here the snippet

```
public class TimeTrackerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public ArrayList<TimeRecord> times=new ArrayList<TimeRecord>();
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return times.size();
    }

    public TimeTrackerAdapter()
    {
        times.add(new TimeRecord("12:30","this is the best"));
        times.add(new TimeRecord("2:30","I need this"));
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return times.get(position);
    }

    public void addTimeRecord(TimeRecord timeRecord)
    {
        times.add(timeRecord);
        notifyDataSetChanged(); 
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(view==null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_layout, parent, false);
        }
        Button button=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.delete_entry);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                times.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged(); 
            }
        });
        TextView timeView=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time_textView);
        TextView noteView=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.note_TextView);
        TimeRecord time=times.get(position);
        timeView.setText(time.getTime());
        noteView.setText(time.getNote());
        return view;
    }
}
```